# Replace region of an image with another image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want to place one image's pattern within the shape of another image using ImageMagick. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, this is how I would suggest you do it. You extract the alpha channel from the second (bubble) image and replace the alpha channel of the first (circle) image with that from the second. You need to resize and center the bubble image to capture the full center circle.

Circle:

[image]

Bubble:

[image]

```
convert circle.png \( bubble.png -resize 120% -alpha extract \) -alpha off -gravity center -geometry +0+30 -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#copyopacity

Comment: The above command is working but i want to remove the rest part of circle image also.Here is your output image(https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3psflif333xqr0/result.png?dl=0). Here is the bubble image url (https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5zv2lbbou8r8ce/b.png?dl=0) and circle url (https://www.dropbox.com/s/qh75uzcv3lwo7py/a.png?dl=0)

Comment: `@Jitendra Mohanta` I have edited my answer above to use your provided images and to change the command to try to deal with the issue you mentioned as I understand it.